# Image taken from camera and encoded to Base64 has bad quality

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, base64

I'm new on android, I'm learning how to use the camera and save pictures in a sqlite database. For that, I'm following this example 
https://github.com/sprejjs/MyMemoriesDB

It's actually really good, the only thing is the quality of the pictures. When you open the camera it looks pretty good, but then, when you save it, looks so bad, lose a lot of quality. How can I increase the quality using that example?

Comment: Sqlite is not really capable of storing hi-rez images

Comment: @androiddevjs if you found the answer correct and useful, please close this question by marking it as answered.

Comment: @ItamarKerbel I'm so sorry I din't mark the correct answer! Your was the correct one. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the code of the library you see that Memory has a constructor:

```
public Memory(String title, Bitmap image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.image = bitmapToString(resizeBitmap(image));
}
```

Note that this constructor calls

> resizeBitmap(image)

if you look at that code you'll see that:

```
public static Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = PREFERRED_WIDTH / width;
    float scaleHeight = PREFERRED_HEIGHT / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    bitmap.recycle();
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

The code actually resizes the image to 250/250 before converting it to Base64.

```
private static final float PREFERRED_WIDTH = 250;
private static final float PREFERRED_HEIGHT = 250;
```

Just change that to what you want at the top of the file or remove the resize call altogether.